# Getting error while using itertools in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

This is the continuation of the [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62787279/6446053) and [OP2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62788260/6446053).

Specifically, the objective is to remove duplicates if more than one `dict` has the same content for the key `paper_title`.

However, the line throw an error if there inconsistency in the way the `list` is imputed, such that if there is a combination of `dict` and `str`

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

The complete code which generates the aforementioned error is as below: -

```
from itertools import groupby



def extract_secondary():
    # 
    test_list = [{"paper_title": 'This is duplicate', 'Paper_year': 2}, \
                 {"paper_title": 'This is duplicate', 'Paper_year': 3}, \
                 {"paper_title": 'Unique One', 'Paper_year': 3}, \
                 {"paper_title": 'Unique two', 'Paper_year': 3}, 'all_result']
    f = lambda x: x["paper_title"]
    already_removed = [next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(test_list, key=f), key=f)]


extract_secondary()
```

May I know which part of the code needs further tweaks? Appreciate any insight.

PS: Please notify me if this thread is being considered duplicate to [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62787279/6446053). However, I believe this thread merits its own existence due to the uniqueness of the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't ask people to download and open a pickle file. Opening a pickle file could lead to arbitrary python code being executed (deleting your entire hard drive for example).  You should update your example to just contain the data in the pickle file.

Comment: There's a `str` in `test_list` instead of `dict` (`"all_result"`). Hence `sorted` is complaining that it cannot use `f` for `str`.

Comment: Thanks for input @Chris, I managed to find the culprit base on your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Chris for pointing about the existence of `str` in `test_lis`t instead of `dict ("all_result")`

To address whereby `sorted` is raise an error that it cannot use f for str, the str need to be removed from the list.

As of [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157160/6446053), the str can be removed by

```
list(filter('all_result'.__ne__, test_list))
```

Note that, for this case, the `str` only have the value of  `'all_result'`.

The complete code then

```
def extract_secondary():

        test_list = [{"paper_title": 'This is duplicate', 'Paper_year': 2}, \
                     {"paper_title": 'This is duplicate', 'Paper_year': 3}, \
                     {"paper_title": 'Unique One', 'Paper_year': 3}, \
                     {"paper_title": 'Unique two', 'Paper_year': 3},'all_result','all_result']
        test_list=list(filter('all_result'.__ne__, test_list))
        f = lambda x: x["paper_title"]
        already_removed = [next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(test_list, key=f), key=f)]

extract_secondary()
```